# How to add inline annotations for QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, annotations, inline, qtextedit

How I can add inline annotations like in Qt Creator? I'm using QTextEdit widget.

Here is a screenshot with inline annotations demontration.
[image: inline annotations qt creator]

Comment: The easiest way probably would be to use the editor from Qt Creator. Otherwise, you have two choices: determine the location of the text block you're annotating, then overpaint. Or you could inject the document elements that represent the annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think...

At first,

let's pick up >a sa dad; line's annotation.

expected ';'

This message is a read-only message.
you can catch the target block by any way.

For example,
`QTextCursor` can search  and catch the last character by using movePosition method with the EndOfLine, KeepAnchor flag.

And if the catched text is not ";",you emit such an annotation.

`QTextEdit` has always its `QTextDocument` object. It is gotten by `document()` method.

This class has `findBlock()` method.

At any rate, `QTextEdit` ,`QTextDocument`,`QTextCursor` should be used for specifing the target positions and the range of rects.

Because the annotation is a read-only,so you override the QTextEdit's paintEvent method and it will do good.

And you make a paint object (`QPainter`).

painter method has drawImage("The image of pop-up" at the first position") and drawText.

painter has setBrush,setPen methods set the red color in `QColor()`

You can utilize the QTextEdit's cursorRect() method and catch the approximate the top-left position for rendering the text,because DrawImage and DrawText methods require rects for their argument so it is very important.This cursorRect() method can be combined with `QTextCursor` pointer.

You add the width of the texts to the rects after measuring by using `QFontMetrics` and so on,it is for viewing all the range of annotation sentence.

If you add the ";" character for repairing your code, research the line and delete the annotation.(probably I think it is good to switch the flags for writing or deleting them in paintEvent operation.)

In advance, you need to make all types of annotation texts (following your own rule) and plan for when and where they are used.